# How to center a TLayout after scaling

Tags: delphi, scale, firemonkey

I have a MyFrame (TFrame) which contains a MyLayout (TLayout) with Align = Center.
I use MyFrame.Scale to reduce/enlarge MyLayout and its content. The scaling works fine. Any thoughts on how to visually center MyLayout within MyFrame after scaling?

Comment: When changing Scale in designtime the position of MyLayout is corrected automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyLayout.Position.X := (Self.Width - MyLayout.Width*newScale.X)/2;
MyLayout.Position.Y := (Self.Height - MyLayout.Height*newScale.Y)/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your layout in a TGridPanelLayout: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Layouts.TGridPanelLayout

If you have a grid with 4 rows and 4 columns, you can put your layout in Cell[1,1] with RowSpan = 2 and ColumnSpan = 2, and change the Align property of the TGridPanelLayout and MyLayout to Client. Then, your layout will always be centered.